# Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, html-table, append

I am creating an google chrome extension where I have created an html table with draft information inside of it and allows the table to be saved in a csv file. My initial goal is to have a new row append to the table every time they visit a new url.

The first function of my popup.js file adds a div element of the url every time a new site has been visited however my goal is to have an row with the url inside the table every time a new site is visited.
I have two functions (addRow and addRowUsingJQuery) that could possible work however neither seems to be working.

My javascript function keeps giving me an error. Do anyone know what the issue could be?

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZVgI.png) -- I keep receiving this error

**manifest.json**

```
{
    //Required naming
    "name" : "Activity logger",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This support includes the development of a  Chrome Browser Activity Logger.",
    
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js", "popup.js"]
        }
        
     ],
     
    
     "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "act.png",
        "default_title": "Activity",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        
     },
     "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
        
     },
     
     
     "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"]
    
    
    
    

}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
        Activity Logger
    </title>
    <style>
    *{
        color:#2b2b2b;
        font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
     }
        table{ width:40%;}
        th{ text-align:left; color:#4679bd}
        tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color:#daeaff;)
        button( cursor:pointer; margin-top:1rem;)
         
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="addRow()">

    <script src="popup.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    
    <h2>Activity Logger</h2>
    
    
    <table id = "tableID" border="1">
        <thead>
        <!--Example table header row with the user, url visited, and time they visited the url etc-->
            <tr>
      <!--categories-->
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Protocol</th> 
                <th>Downloaded File Names</th> 
                <th>Description</th>
      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id= "tbodyID">
          <tr>
            <!--1st row-->
                <td>Google</td>
                <td>000000</td>
                <td>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</td>
                <td>example</td>
                <td>example</td>
                <td>example</td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
     <!--Goal is to append to this table-->
 

    </table>
   <!--when clicked it, ID uses function, exportTableToCSV to download file-->
<a id="click-this">
    <u> Save as CSV </u>
    </a>

</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
//loads element url on page
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   
  const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
  Object.keys(bg.bears).forEach(function (url) {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.textContent = `${url}`
    document.body.appendChild(div)
    
  })


}, false)



// creates ID to export table to csv--works
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", exportTableToCSV);
 
    
});


/*document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("click-this").addEventListener("click", addRow);
 
    
});
*/




//function to append row to HTML table --underwork--
function addRow() {
        //perhaps need an for loop for every page visited 
    
    const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()    
    Object.keys(bg.bears).forEach(function (url) {
    
    //get html table
        // Append product to the table
    var table = document.getElementById("tbodyID");
    
    // add new empty row to the table
                  //1 = in the top 
                  //table.rows.length = the end
                  //table.rows.length/2+1 = the center 

            var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
                  
                  // add cells to the row
                  var nameCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                  var urlCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var timeCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  
                  // add the data to the cells
                  nameCell.innerHTML = name; 
                  urlCell.innerHTML = `${url}`; 
                  timeCell.innerHTML = time;
                  console.log("works");
     }) 
            }
addRow()
//console.log(addRowUsingJquery);

//perhaps add row using JQuery--underwork
/*function addRowUsingJquery() {
    // Get a reference to table
    let table = document.querySelector('#tableID');
    
    const add = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()
    Object.keys(add.bears).forEach(function (url) {
    
       
        
    // Build the row
        let template = `
                <tr>
                        <td>${USERNAME}</td>
                        <td>${`url`}</td>
                        <td>${TIMESTAMP}</td>
                </tr>`;

    // Add the row to the end of the table
        table.innerHTML += template; 
        console.log("works");
        
     })


}

 */                          

//function to for onClick function--works
function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;
    
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type:"text/csv"});
                       
                       
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    downloadLink.setAttribute("download", "ChromeLog.csv");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    
    downloadLink.click();
}

//function to export HTML table to csv file--works
function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
        for(var j=0; j < cols.length; j++)
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);
        
        csv.push(row.join(","));
    }   
       
   
    //download csv file
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
    
    
}
```

If anyone know how to resolve this issue on why my addRow functions isn't working and how to write the functions correctly, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you put your script tag to the very bottom of the body tag

Comment: @KaanCetinkaya Thank you so much, that fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your script tag to the very bottom of the body tag